# replace non-alphamumeric and multiple spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex to remove all non-alphanumeric characters.

```
a = a.replace(/[^0-9a-z]+/gi,'');
```

Any help to add to this line to replace all multiple spaces with a single space.

Thanks.

Comment: `a.replace(/[^0-9a-z]+/gi,'').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')`

Comment: is it for multiple or just for two spaces?

Comment: `{2,}` means 2 or more

Comment: thanks a lot. solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this in a single regular expression, you can alternate with capturing the space in a group, and then replace with that group (which will be the empty string if the other alternation was used):

```js
const replace = str => str.replace(/( )+|[^\da-z ]+/gi, '$1');
console.log(replace('foobar'));
console.log(replace('foo       bar'));
console.log(replace('foo###bar'));
```

Also note that `0-9` can be replaced with `\d`, which is a bit nicer to read IMO.

Comment: coul you a bit explain, pls, where is the code for replacing multipla spaces, pls

Comment: `( )+` repeats spaces (one or more) and captures a single space in a group. `( ){2,}` would work too